# How to clear a checkbox that is populated from a list in C#?

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have a ListBox with each item having a checkbox next to it. The checkbox and text field are bound to a list, and i generate this based on a sql query,

```
SqlDataReader sdr = sql.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            _callSubjectsList.Add(new CallSubjects
            {
                SubjectId = sdr["SubjectID"].ToString(),
                Subject = sdr["Subject"].ToString(),
                Chosen = false,
            });
        }
```

Chosen is my checkbox field. the problem i am having is after checkboxes have been checked and the save process has run, when I try to loop through and clear out the checkboxes I cannot. I can't just set the "Chosen" value in the list the "false" as this is not causing the checkbox to be unchecked. is there a way to do this the way i have it? everything is working except for this. i am sure there is a better way to do it though, open to suggestions. thanks!

Comment: What's the kind of this app? Web (ASP.NET), WinForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a checkbox.  You need to set the property of the check in the checkbox = false.

```
 myCheckBox.Checked = false;
```

Comment: Should be myCheckBox.Checked = false; - but yeah

Comment: How do I access that property considering I am looping through the results:

Comment: foreach (SupportDesk.CallSubjects itemRow in _callSubjectsList)
            {

Comment: based on that, i have been using: Boolean chosen = itemRow.Chosen; to test if it is checked or not. there isn't a Checked property because i am referring to the list, how can i access the checkbox property based on this, or do i need to loop through the array of checkboxes in some way?

Comment: You would need to loop through the array of the checkboxes and set the Checked property to false;

Comment: found a way to do without using the Checked property, just changed my List to an ObservableCollection then cleared out the list and reloaded after saving.